# Change background color if width is bigger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background color if width is bigger than 100.

This is my code but it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#mydiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">
function () {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var curr_width = parseInt(mydiv.style.width);
    if (curr_width > 100) {
    mydiv.style.BackgroundColor = "blue";
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv" style=""></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your function dont have a name? and where do you call it?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
parseInt(mydiv.style.width);
mydiv.style.BackgroundColor = "blue";
```

To

```
mydiv.offsetWidth
mydiv.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var curr_width = mydiv.offsetWidth;
```

instead

```
var curr_width = parseInt(mydiv.style.width);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var curr_width = parseInt(mydiv.style.width);
mydiv.style.BackgroundColor = "blue";
```

to:

```
var curr_width = mydiv.offsetWidth;
mydiv.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

I have set up a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f710j70u/2/).

Also notice I took it out of the function because it looked like it wasn't being called anywhere. You should also move the script out of the head to the bottom of the body tag or use window.onload.

**UPDATE**

[Another fiddle with everything together](http://jsfiddle.net/ms66hjuz/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a duplicate question.
Anyway, your intialization of curr_width need not include parseInt.
parseInt is for converting a value to integer type and here you doesnt require it.

Your code can be re-written as

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    div#mydiv {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function () {
        var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
        var curr_width = mydiv.offsetWidth;
        if (curr_width > 100) {
        mydiv.style.BackgroundColor = "blue";
        }
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="mydiv" style=""></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function to be called onload. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#mydiv {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">
function load(){
var mydiv = parseInt(document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetWidth);
if (mydiv > 100) {
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="load();">

<div id="mydiv" style=""></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Changes:**

- Use **offsetWidth** to get the width of the div.
- Use **backgroundColor** instead of **BackgroundColor**.

Answer (score 0):

To get a proper computed width, you need to use the (not enough used) method getBoundingClientRect() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect

Latest browsers have `.width` property, otherwise you just need to take `right - left` to get it.

Some comments:
- `language="JavaScript"` is useless. Like `type="text/javascript"`. It's the default behavior. Seriously.
- you need to execute your code after the div has been created. So using `onload` or just by calling the code after in the html (like in my example)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#mydiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script>
  /* run the code after the creation of #mydiv */
  var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  var clientRect = mydiv.getBoundingClientRect()
  var curr_width = clientRect.width || (clientRect.right - clientRect.left);
  if (curr_width > 100) {
    mydiv.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a working example http://jsbin.com/xapet/1/edit

---

Warning: to do this properly it's recommended that you execute this code each time the browser is resized.
Maybe you can take a look to the "element queries" thing, that will be a nice workaround according to media queries limitations.

https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=element%20queries%20css